# Ktor equivalent of "Context" from project Reactor?

Tags: ktor

In project Reactor there is the concept of a `Context` which is a key value store that can be shared across components. We use it in some of our projects to manage the correlationId. API Reference: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/context/Context.html

I am wondering in ktor is there a similar concept? I want a way to manage shared things such as a correlationId throughout the application that I can then pull from when making a client request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin has a concept of a CoroutineContext which is similar to what you need - it's a map-like structure carried with every coroutine.
It's vaguely defined in the official documentation: [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/).
And this is how it for instance can be used for tracing: https://github.com/Shinigami072/OpenTracing-Kotlin-Coroutine-Integration/blob/master/coroutine-tracing-api-core/src/main/kotlin/ActiveSpan.kt